# R: producing vector with number of times an element appears in sample

Tags: r, loops, vector, random, sample

I have a homework problem where I have a sample of 30 men, a random sampling of 10 of them:

> men
>    [1] 15 18 14  6 22 17 20  3 16  9

And From them, do 12 random samples and determine how many times each man appears.

The problem statement, verbatim, is "Perform 12 samples of 10 men from a population of size 30 and for each man, record the number
samples in which he appears."

I have attempted a loop for the problem that would produce a vector of 10 elements, each one lined up with the appropriate index.

```
mtimes<-rep(0,12)
> repeat{
+ mtimes[menind]<-sum(sample(pop1,12,replace = TRUE) == men[menind])
+ menind = menind + 1
+ if (menind == 10){
+ break
+ }
+ }
```

This resulted in a vector:

> mtimes
>    [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

It seems the 3rd man should not have appeared only once while no one else appeared in the samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replicate` and `table` here

```
set.seed(1)
table(replicate(n = 12, expr = sample(30, size = 10, replace = TRUE)))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
# 3  2  3  5  2  2  5  5  3  3  6  7  4  5  8  2  1  3  2  9  3  7  2  8  3  3  5  3  3  3
```

I assume that by "men" you mean `1:30`.

---

Another option would be to increase the size of the sample to 10*12 as in

```
set.seed(1)
table(sample(30, size = 10*12, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: "men" is the set of 10 elements randomly sampled from 1:30. I realize now that I left out pop1 <- 1:30 from my post. I'll try the replicate and table functions with the appropriate set. Thank you!